# Timestamp doesn't work in batch file

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

```
c:
cd c:\ffmpeg\bin
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 320x240 -framerate 30 -pixel_format yuv420p -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910" -t 00:00:10 C:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910" C:\ffmpeg\bin\picture1.jpeg
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910" C:\ffmpeg\bin\picture2.jpeg
move C:\ffmpeg\bin\picture1.jpeg C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TestFolder
move C:\ffmpeg\bin\picture2.jpeg C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TestFolder
move C:\ffmpeg\bin\video.mp4 C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TestFolder
ren C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TestFolder\picture1.jpeg Picture-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.jpeg
ren C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TestFolder\picture2.jpeg Picture-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.jpeg
ren C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\TestFolder\video.mp4 Video-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.mp4
taskkill /im ffmpeg.exe /t /f
```

I've created a batch file that will take a ten second video and two screenshots from my webcam. My batch file works correctly until I try to rename the files. I don't understand why it is not working because I've used this code on another computer before and just copied, pasted it, and adjusted the file names around so it would work for my purposes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These parts, `%.mp4` & `%.jpg` should be `.mp4` & `.jpg`, you've overdone the number of percent characters! Also, bear in mind, _as I'm not sure if it was intended_, that each one of your renamed timestamps are unlikely to match as time will have moved between each invokation.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. It doesn't matter that the timestamp is slightly off from when the actual video and pictures were taken. I just need a way to identify approximately when the image was taken.

Comment: The usual method is to create the timestamp once as a variable, then use that variable throughout, so that they do match.

Comment: I will look into that. I've never used batch files before so this is pretty new to me.

Comment: To do that use `Set "dtStamp=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s"` then you can rename to `Picture|Video-%dtStamp%.jpeg|mp4`

Comment: Not working: Does your script removes `System32`?